# Android - Log information in a file that can be accessed by computer

Tags: android, io

I have an Android app and I try to log certain things when some events happen, but I create the file which is being seen in the following location /storage/emulated/0/Log.txt but when I plug the terminal in the computer I can't see the file.

I use the following code:

```
//Instantiating variables
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Log.txt");
logFOS = new FileOutputStream(file);

//Writing in the file
logFOS.write(new String("Time:" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + "|Layout:" + ((firstLayout)?1:2) + "|Mark finished:" + entry.getKey() + "|Drone: "+ listen.getAgentID()).getBytes());

//Permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

What is the problem because of which I cant see the file?

If you offer code please explain as I want to learn!

Regards,

Dan

Comment: I would recommend using a `.ini` file instead of `.txt`

Comment: @tardoandre Could you please explain why would you recommend this? Would it solve the problem?

Comment: You can use normal `.txt` files, but generally it's alot more sensitive: hard coded order of keys, capitalization sensitivity and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing USB connection mode from Camera to Media.

If it doesn't works, `reboot` your phone.

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning behind your answer? Thanks!